# Converting from XML to CSV w/ XSLT 1.0, getting blank line

Tags: xml, csv, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML file (I'm cutting down both the XML and XSLT here for illustration purposes; in the real XML document, there's a lot more data I care about, as well as a lot more that I don't care about, and there are usually on the order of a dozen `<Document>` tags, not just the two here):

```
<DocumentList>
  <Document>
    <SerialNumber>74631225</SerialNumber>
    <MailRoomDate>2011-12-27-05:00</MailRoomDate>
    <DocumentTypeCode>URC</DocumentTypeCode>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <SerialNumber>74631225</SerialNumber>
    <MailRoomDate>2011-12-19-05:00</MailRoomDate>
    <DocumentTypeCode>IPC</DocumentTypeCode>
  </Document>
</DocumentList>
```

I want to turn this into comma-separated values, with each document preceded and followed with delimiter lines (BeginRepeatedField and EndRepeatedField, respectively) as shown below:

```
BeginRepeatedField,"Document"
ApplicationNumber,"74631225"
MailRoomDate,"2011-12-27-05:00"
DocumentTypeCode,"URC"
EndRepeatedField,"Document"
BeginRepeatedField,"Document"
ApplicationNumber,"74631225"
MailRoomDate,"2011-12-19-05:00"
DocumentTypeCode,"IPC"
EndRepeatedField,"Document"
```

Here's my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:variable name='NL'><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:variable><!-- NL = newline character X'0A' -->
<xsl:template match="Document">
BeginRepeatedField,"Document"<xsl:text/>
ApplicationNumber,"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(SerialNumber)"/>"<xsl:text/>
MailRoomDate,"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(MailRoomDate)"/>"<xsl:text/>
DocumentTypeCode,"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(DocumentTypeCode)"/>"<xsl:text/>
EndRepeatedField,"Document"<xsl:text/>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use this, I get an extra blank line at the beginning of the file. Now, I asked a similar question in a similar context while back -- [One pesky blank line in an XSLT transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823425/one-pesky-blank-line-in-an-xslt-transform) -- and applying what I learned there, I changed the first line in the template to precede with a `<xsl:text/>`:

```
<xsl:text/>BeginRepeatedField,"Document"<xsl:text/>
```

And that did get rid of the blank line; however, when I do that, the closing delimiter line from the first document and the opening delimiter from the second document get concatenated:

```
EndRepeatedField,"Document"BeginRepeatedField,"Document"
```

I can get around *that* by removing the `<xsl:text/>` from the last line in the end of the template:

```
EndRepeatedField,"Document"
```

or by explicitly adding a newline:

```
EndRepeatedField,"Document"<xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select='$NL' />
```

And, in both of those cases, I don't get the blank line at the top of the file, and I don't get that unwanted concatenation; but now I get a blank line at the *end* of the file.

Everything I've tried either leaves me with an unwanted blank line (either at the top or the bottom), or else has that unwanted concatenation. Any solution? For example, any way to *conditionally* add a new line in all but the first `<Document>`?

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:text/>` is an empty, self-closing element that doesn't do anything.

To output literal text, put it **inside** an `xsl:text` element, using opening `<xsl:text>` and closing `</xsl:text>` tags - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="Document">
<xsl:text>BeginRepeatedField,"Document"</xsl:text>
...
```

What you have now outputs the entire text node between `<xsl:template match="Document">` and `<xsl:text/>`, including the newline character/s.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still produces the concatenation error.

Comment: @codingatty You need to place a newline at the end of a document. If you don't want to have a trailing newline after the last one, do it conditionally - see, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529261/xsl-printing-linebreak-but-leave-out-last-line-break/21584607#21584607

Answer (score 0):

I may have it. I'm not sure this is the best approach, but it seems to work...

I found out how to conditionally add a newline. So I set the last template line to suppress the newline:

```
EndRepeatedField,"Document"<xsl:text/>
```

And then added the newline unless it was the last `<Document>`:

```
<xsl:if test="position () != last()">
    <xsl:value-of select='$NL' />
</xsl:if>
```

That *seems* to be working; subject to further testing.

Comment: Adding the newline conditionally as you have done is correct. Using an empty `xsl:text` element is wrong.

Comment: Thanks; but without the empty xsl:text element, an additional blank line inserted between each of the delimiter lines in the output. It may be aesthetically wrong, but it does make it work.

You raise a real good point a few comments up. I've found that other CSV-producing programs do include the newline on the final line, so I may rethink this to be consistent with that; and alter the program this feeds into to accept that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: "*without the empty xsl:text element, an additional blank line inserted between each of the delimiter lines in the output.*" No, not if you follow what I said in my answer. What you're doing is a hack that happens to work (and BTW would work with any other empty element, not just `xsl:text`).